# Logstash Date Filter not setting timestamp properly

Tags: logstash

I am trying to set the `@timestamp` property by the time received in the logfile.

the datetime in the log file has the following values: `08/15/2017 01:29:59.453 PM`

to parse it i am using

```
    date
    {
            match => [ "datetime", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS a"]
    }
```

`

but, after parsing the `@timestamp` values is shown as `August 15th 2017, 01:29:59.453 AM`

which is wrong as the hours should either be 13:29 (24hour format) or 01:29 PM (half-day format)

My guess is it is ignoring the halfday of day (am / pm )

I tried parsing the same format with the same input field using joda time debugger and there it is working fine as well

any pointers would help

Comment: not sure if it is relevant or not, but i use capital Y for year parsing. Such as `MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss.SSS a`. I am not dealing with halfday though

Comment: Year is getting parsed properly the only challenge is with AM PM

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify my point. The match option of the date filter accepts a list of 0+ patterns to match the field in a date. 0+ means you can specify no patterns at all. So I am thinking: is it possible that your pattern is failing for some reason (and one possible reason is the year character that I suggested) and the match is using a default template, that ignores the am/pm part?

Comment: What happens if you try other hours? Is it always same day, changing PM for AM? If you parse 1 AM, what do you get? ES uses UTC always, so it could be that it's parsing in UTC. Just a thought.

Comment: @Imma for 1 am also it was also parsing as 1 am., In the meanwhile something strange has happened, I tried restarting the log stash and cleared the cache, deleted the indexes and also mappings and now it seems to be working fine, will.do more checks tonsee if this is  indeed fixed